# Deleting a resource in Azure - Does it delete Alerts associated with it

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, sql-azure-alerts, azure-elasticpool

When we delete elastic pool in Azure environment, Alerts associated with the elastic pool are not getting deleted.

I see they are getting disabled. does anyone know if this is expected or a bug?

FYI: List of Disabled Alerts
Get-AzureRmAlertRule -ResourceGroup "resourcegroupname"  -DetailedOutput | Where-Object {$*.Name -like "filterCriteria*" -and $*.Properties.Status -ne "Enabled"}  | select Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alerts are separate Azure resources and will need to be deleted separately. If you provision the elastic pool and related alerts in the same resource group, when you delete the resource group all the resources in the resource group will be deleted.